# How to make MainThread wait till some async action is done?

Tags: objective-c, ios, multithreading, uitableview, asynchronous

I have `UITableView` with some content, which is loaded in **asynchronous** way. When user rotates the device I need to make `[tableView reloadData]` in `-willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method. ReloadData works asynchronous in my case.

**I understand that reloadData works in main thread, but it fires cellForRowAtIndexPath, which works async in my case.**

So the question is how to make main thread wait till `UITableView's reloadData` ends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call reloadData from willRotateToInterfaceOrientation then it is called on the main thread.  In fact UIViews are NOT thread safe and should only ever be dealt with from the main thread (in case for some reason someone gets the idea to call reloadData from another thread).

I think there is confusion relating to "asynchronous" as a term.  Asynchronous callbacks for UI delegates like willRotateToInterfaceOrientation are called on the main thread.  To be asynchronous does not necessarily mean a different thread (though running asynchronously "in parallel" does).

I would recommend reading up on the Apple documentation for NSRunLoop.  It is an integral part of the way iOS apps run and is a must for app programmers to understand.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html

Comment: I understand that reloadData is called in main thread. But realodData calls cellForRowAtIndexPath... and this method needs to load some data async.

Comment: I see, so you aren't waiting for reloadData to complete but the asynchronous tasks that reloadData fires off to complete.  Could you modify your question to reflect this?  NSRunLoop is still what you want, though I'm not understanding why youd want to hold you main thread hostage while asynchronous data loads.

Comment: A need main thread to wait reloadData, because this will make rotation animation pleasant.

Comment: I'm sorry George, that statement does not tell me anything that can help to help you.  Perhaps identify the problem you are trying to solve and illustrate it with a code example so that we can follow you and come up with the solution.  Though waiting for the main thread may work, you are stating the solution that you want us to help you implement without identifying the problem.  If we can assess the problem first, the users at SO can often help identify a solution as well as what is required for implementation.

Answer (score 3):

You may use [CFRunLoopRun](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRunLoopRun)
to make your main thread wait until UITableView data is reloaded. After data is reloaded call [CFRunLoopStop](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRunLoopStop) passing result of [CFRunLoopGetMain](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFRunLoopRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CFRunLoopGetMain) as parameter.

Comment: Thanks, i see this in not so easy to do reading the documentation. I will try to understand.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to load your table's data in the background, then call UITableView's reloadData method.

You can use GCD to easily dispatch your load function asynchronously to a background queue. When that task is finished, have the worker thread dispatch back to the main thread a block that calls `[tableView reloadData]`. Here's how:

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration{

  ...
  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
  dispatch_async(queue, ^{

     // load your table data here
     [self loadMyTableData];

     // when done dispatch back to the main queue to load the table
     dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
     dispatch_async(mainQueue, ^{

        [self.tableView reloadData];
      });
  });
  ...
}
```

Comment: To make    [self loadMyTableData];  i need to change half of the code to store the data and than to push it to my subclassed uitableviewcells and it's content